# Android 3.6 ViewStubProxy Unresolved reference

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, android-viewbinding

I have this Kotlin code:

```
if(this.fragmentMeasurementBinding.viewStub.isInflated)
{
    return;
}
this.fragmentMeasurementBinding.viewStub.viewStub?.layoutResource =
      R.layout.layout_measurement_single_value
this.fragmentMeasurementBinding.viewStub.setOnInflateListener { _, inflated ->
      LayoutMeasurementSingleValueBinding.bind(inflated)?.let {
          it.textInputLayoutSingleMeasurementValue.hint = Helper.getDynamicStringResource(
            this.context, parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(), prefix = "title_")
      }
}
this.fragmentMeasurementBinding.viewStub.viewStub?.inflate()
```

And this on my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.MeasurementFragment">

    <ViewStub
        android:id="@+id/viewStub"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_input_layout_measure" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/text_input_layout_measure"
        style="@style/AppTheme.Widget.TextInput.ExposedDropdownMenu"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/exposed_dropdown_measure"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/what_are_you_measure"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:labelFor="@id/text_input_layout_measure" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

When I compile the Android studio report the following errors:

- Unresolved reference: isInflated
- Unresolved reference: viewStub
- Unresolved reference: viewStub

I am using the new ViewBinding from Google I am develop with Android Studio 3.6 Canary 12, Gradle 3.6.0-alpha12.
This is a bug from Android Studio or my bug?

Comment: I have the same with simple view binding and Android studio 3.6.1

Comment: Sounds like a bug [you may want to report](https://developer.android.com/studio/report-bugs)

Comment: Curious if you ever solved this. I am running into this now, but only for some files in my project.

Comment: Any news on this? I'm also interested.

Comment: I also would like an update if this ever gets fixed

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem.

I checked how BindingClass is actually generated.
The generated class is in build/generated/databinding base_class_source_out folder.

The ViewStubProxy that cause problem is actually implemented as ViewStub in generated class.
After I converted layout xml and target layout xml to data binding layout, the problem is gone.

Answer (score 0):

I use `ViewBinding` everywhere, however, due to this issue with the `ViewStubProxy Unresolved reference` that I cannot find a solution either, in this particular case, I use the good friend `findViewById`.

For instance:

```
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity{

    //...

    private val myView: View by lazy {
        findViewById<ViewStub>(R.id.my_view_stub).inflate()
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        //...
    }

    //...

    fun displayMyView() {
        myView.isVisible = true
        //
    }

}
```

Or if you require to work with the inner views of your inflated stub using the binding:

```
private val myViewBinding: MyViewBinding by lazy {
    MyViewBinding.bind(findViewById<ViewStub>(R.id.my_view_stub).inflate())
}
```